# Drag and Drop on a fixed size collection view crashes when the auto-reordering forces the collection view to go beyond the maximum number of sections

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop, swift4

The real example I am using has a collection view which is two side-scrolling rows of infinite length. When I drag and drop in this collection, the automatic re-ordering sometimes tries to create a third row, which crashes the app.

I've put together a minimum working example below.

Is there a function which broadly does "please be sensible and work out a way of reordering yourself without going out of bounds"? Failing that, how can I override the drag and drop standard behaviour to stop this happening?

Thanks in advance!

[animated gif of crash on this link](https://giphy.com/embed/dhsEYpX0bawgdrepAm)

```
import UIKit
private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
class CustomCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    var counter = 1
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.dragDelegate = self
        collectionView.dropDelegate = self
        collectionView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int{ return 3
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4 }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        cell.label.text = String(counter)
        counter = counter + 1

        return cell
    }
}

extension CustomCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDragDelegate{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem]
    {
        let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

        let item = cell.label.text
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: item! as String as NSItemProviderWriting)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)

        return [dragItem]
    } 
}

extension CustomCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDropDelegate{
    public func canHandle(_ session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
        return session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: NSString.self)
    }
    func  collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {
        if collectionView.hasActiveDrag{
            if session.items.count > 1 {
                return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel)
            }
            else{
                return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
            }
        }
        else{
            return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .copy, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {

        let destinationIndexPath: IndexPath
        if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath{
            destinationIndexPath = indexPath
        }
        else{
           destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        }
        self.collectionView.moveItem(at: (coordinator.items.first?.sourceIndexPath)!, to: destinationIndexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: And a side question being "How do people embed animated screen captures in their questions". The link ^^^ is a video of the crash - bu I can't figure how to embed it!

Answer (score 1):

OK - what I ended up doing is as follows:

I set up several parallel single section collection views with single sections - rather than one collection view with several sections.

Feels a bit odd to use a collection view this way - but it works now - both to have constraints and to have drag and drops....